# AJAX Load Polymer Element and run it's methods

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, ecmascript-6, polymer-1.0

Here is my situation: I have an app shell and have controller classes to load templates which have custom polymer elements in it. So far I load the template and add to the DOM and everything is work fine for first sight.

After the template contents are added to the DOM I try to access to the custom-element methods but I could not access to it. If I try to debug the code and run the important steps in console then I can acces to the element methods.

**My Element:**

```html
<link rel="import" href="../../components/polymer/polymer.html" />
<dom-module is="app-login">
<template>
    <style>
       :host { display: block; }
       :host.hide { display: none; }
    </style>
    <div> samle content </div>
</template>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'app-login',
    run: function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            resolve({'id':0,'name':'user'});
        });
    },
    close: function() {
        this.classList.add('hide');
    }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
```

**My Program:**

```js
// [...]
// this works fine, I just add for better understanding
getTemplate( templateName ) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        fetch( 'templates/'+templateName+'.html' ).then(response => {
            document.getElementById('templates').innerHTML += response.text();
            resolve(response);
        }).catch(error => { reject(error); });
    });
};
// [...]
// this method called by the main program and cant't access to the element methods
doLogin() {
    this.getTemplate('login').then(templateResponse => {
        let Login = document.querySelector('app-login'); // <app-login>...</app-login>
        Login.run(); // TypeError: Login.run is not a function
    });
};
// [...]
```

**templates/login.html:**

```html
<link rel="import" href="elements/app-login/app-login.html" />
<app-login></app-login>
```

**Console debugging:**

```js
let Login = document.querySelector('app-login');
//Return: <app-login>...</app-login>
Login.run();
//Return: Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

I tried search for this but I could not find any relevant answer yet, somebody solved this issue in some way before?

**Already tried:**

- setTimeout after adding element to the DOM » same result
- adding _ to the method name (like paper elements methods) » same result
- waiting for WebComponentsReady event after inserting the element into the DOM » event not fired, the program stopped

Comment: @a1626 have any ideas? :) I feel that I just use one little thing wrong like last time.

Comment: strangely, i never received any notification for this post mention.

Comment: ya got it this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in the topic and asking for help on polymer-dev group on google; Karl Tiedt (@ktiedt) solved my problem:

The solution was the using the Polymer importHref and dom().appendChild instead of simple responseText append to the container element. The methods was not available beacuse the element parsing is different and far as I belive the javascript cannot access to the element shadowDOM if you append the HTML text to the innerHTML of the container.

I changed the getTemplate method to use the Polymer importHref and append the container with Polymer.dom().appendChild.

Information about the importHref usage: 
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#imports-and-urls

```
getTemplate( templateName )
{
    let templateFile = this.baseURL+'templates/'+templateName+'.html';

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        let templateRequest = Polymer.Base.importHref(templateFile,
        function()
        {
            Polymer.dom(document.getElementById('templates'))
                   .appendChild(templateRequest.import.body);

            resolve(templateRequest);
        },
        function(error)
        {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Hah, just got back from lunch, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: @ktiedt :D It's night at my place, but copy and paste the answer (with correction, because im not sure about the access problem real reason)